# Variable project_loc contains no value

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In Oxygen, when I attempt to launch an external tool which has the working directory defined as **${project_loc}/docs**, Eclipse complains that "Variable references empty selection: ${project_loc}". I currently have the project selected in Package Explorer. I am running in the Pydev perspective. How can I correct this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening there, but when I created a "New Program" as an external tool and pointed the location to `python.exe` and working directory with `${project_loc}` and as arguments `-c "import os;print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))"` it did run and print the project selected in the `PyDev Package Explorer` properly (so... not much help, but the same thing worked for me).

Comment: It works if I use an explicit directory but I want to make it work with any project.